# UITapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2 not working

Tags: iphone, ios, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

I added UITapGestureRecognizer for UIImageView in both single tap and double tap. for single tap method A will call and for double tap method B will call.

its working perfectly for first time only.

**First Time**

If i made single tap on UIImageView, method A called as expected.

If i made double tap on UIImageView, method B called as expected.

**Second Time**

If i made single tap on UIImageView, method A called as expected.

If i made double tap on UIImageView, method B not called again method A only called.
I do not know where i am making problem.

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideHandle:)];
[gestureRecognizer setDelegate:self];
[userResizableView addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
[gestureRecognizer release];

UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer1 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
gestureRecognizer1.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;

[gestureRecognizer1 setDelegate:self];
[userResizableView addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer1];
[gestureRecognizer1 release];

[gestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:gestureRecognizer1];
```

Comment: If you have implemented the delegate method for gesturerecognizerdelegate could you please post this?

Comment: I found the problem. i used removeGestureRecognizer in double tap delegate method defination. that was the problem. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score -1):

I have tested your code and it worked fine!

You are adding requireGestureRecognizerToFail after releasing gestureRecognizer1. This shouldn't be an issue as I tested after following comments and edited this answer but give it a go. Also give some meaningful names to variables and methods.

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                            initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];
    doubleTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    [userResizableView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTapGestureRecognizer];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                            initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    singleTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [singleTapGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail: doubleTapGestureRecognizer];
    [userResizableView addGestureRecognizer:singleTapGestureRecognizer];

    [doubleTapGestureRecognizer release];
    [singleTapGestureRecognizer release];
```

Comment: The delegate for a UITagGestureRecognizer is set to determine if the tag gesture selector is fired or not.  These are orthogonal actions, defining a selector and setting a delegate.  Also, I suspect that the release is not the problem, as the view that the gesturerecognizer is added to retains the gesturerecognizer.

Comment: The view will retain it off course but using the same object after releasing it which is pointing to garbage memory will cause a problem! Let's wait for questionar to come back and remove your down vote then. LOL

Comment: @banDedo you are right buddy. I am taking my words back! I tested it and it retains the object and works fine either way. I am wondering how? When you release the object reference count decremented and that object will be dangling reference. The memory pointed by the object won't release because reference count won't be zero! It shouldn't work actually!! Am I missing something fundamentally? Thumbs up for your comment :-)

Comment: @applefreak... no ill will meant over the down vote, but I think it should stay to guide onlookers to not trust the answer.  With that being said, let's review the trajectory of the retain count for the recognizer.  1) +1 for alloc, 2) +1 for addGestureRecognizer: call, 3) -1 for release.  Its retain count is still +1, until the view that holds it is dealloced.  I think this is the source of the misunderstanding.  Let me know if you need more detail :)

Comment: buddy there will be two memory locations occupied by any object. One is for itself and one is for the data it is pointing to. When you release the object, the memory occupied by itself will be added to free memory queue but as reference count is not zero, the memory pointed by this object where data resided won't be freed as some other pointer still pointing that memory. If you use object after releasing it, it's your good luck that the freed memory hasn't been assigned to any other object and it has still valid data. This will cause a definitely problem in high threading system!

Comment: What you have written above about dangling pointers is true, except that this argument does not have validity until the object in question has been fully released.  The gestureRecognizer will not be released until the view that holds it is released in this case.  Do you disagree with the trajectory of the retain count that I mapped out above?

Comment: You not getting what I mean! You have been rounding around view that holds the data pointed by gesterrecogniser pointer but not the pointer itself!!! We are releasing pointer means it no more pointing to the memory occupied by it and it shouldn't be used!!!

Comment: 'release' is a message passed to the underlying data to alter the retain count of that object.  It does not affect the pointer memory location at all.  To change the location of the memory address that the pointer points to you must use an ASSIGNMENT (pointer = ...) operator.  Your analysis is far from the reality of how message passing works.  As proof create an object with a retain count of two by adding an extra retain.  Use lldb to print the memory address of the pointer, release it once to take the retain count to one, then print the memory address again; it will be the same address.

Comment: I agree it will be same address unless it is allocated to some other object! and it will happen in highly multithreaded environment! In short I would say it's not the best practice to use reference of the released object!